# Range for loop for empty initializer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list, perfect-forwarding, range-based-loop

I was reading about forwarding references on cpp reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references and I was interested to learn that there is a special case for forwarding references:

```
auto&& z = {1, 2, 3}; // *not* a forwarding reference (special case for initializer lists)
```

So I started experimenting on godbolt (as a side note I'd be interested to know why this special case is needed). I was slightly surprised to find I could iterate over an initialiser list like so:

```
for (auto&& x : {1, 2, 3})
{
    // do something 
}
```

Until I realised that x was deduced as `int` and that therefore the following wouldn't work:

```
for (auto&& x : {{1}})
{
    // do something
}
```

So I think here, Auto couldn't deduce the initialiser list, because of the special case mentioned above?

Then I tried an empty list, which didn't compile also:

```
for (auto&& x : {})
{
    // do something
}
```

The compiler error message using GCC suggests that this is because it couldn't deduce auto from the empty list, so I then tried the following:

```
for (int x : {})
{
    // do something
}
```

To explicitly tell the compiler that it's an empty list of type `int`. This surprised me, I expected that since I had explicitly given the type, it could deduce what {} was, especially since iterating over a populated version of the initialiser list worked. After some experimentation I found that the following line also does not compile:

```
auto x{};
```

So I think the reason you can't iterate over the empty initialiser list is because it cannot deduce the inner type and therefore can't construct it in the first place.

I would like some clarity on my thoughts and reasoning here

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is a class template with a type template parameter. The compiler needs to know what that type `T` is in order to instantiate it. Now in the case of `auto x{};`, how is the compiler supposed to know what specialization of `std::initializer_list<T>` is meant to be used?

Comment: @digito_evo that makes sense in the case of `auto x{};`. But in theory, the compiler could deduce T in the case of `for (int x : {})` since I have said the type of x is `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the special case:

```cpp
auto&& z = {1, 2, 3};
```

In this case, `auto&&` isn't really deducible to anything, because initializer lists must always receive their type from the context where they're used (such as function parameters, copy initialization, etc.

However, the language has added a few *"fallback cases*" where we simply treat such initializer lists as [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).
The example above is one of those cases, and `z` will be of type `std::initializer_list<int>&&`.
I.e., `z` is not a forwarding reference, but an rvalue reference.
We know that it's `std::initializer_list<int>` because all of the expressions in `{1, 2, 3}` are `int`.

*Note: the term "initializer list" refers to the language construct `{...}` (as in [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)), which is not necessarily [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).*

#### Initializer lists in for-loops

```cpp
for (auto&& x : {1, 2, 3}) { /* ... */ }
```

We can make sense of what happens by expanding it:

```cpp
/* init-statement */
auto &&__range = {1, 2, 3};
auto __begin = begin(__range)
auto __end = end(__range);

for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    auto&& x = *begin;
    /* ... */
}
```

This is exactly what [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) expand to since C++20.

Note that `x` is a forwarding reference here, and that has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`. It always is, regardless of what we're iterating over.

Anyhow, `: {1, 2, 3}` works because we initialize `__range` with it, just like in the original example with `z`.
`__range` will then be an rvalue reference to a `std::initializer_list`.

#### Broken cases

```cpp
{{1}}
```

doesn't compile because the inner `{1}` cannot deduce what is being initialized using the braces here.
This is not one of those cases where we can fall back onto `std::initializer_list`.

```cpp
for (auto x : {})
// and
for (int x : {})
```

These two also don't work, because as you've seen in the expansion above, the `int` isn't giving any hint as to what type the `std::initializer_list` should be.
The type of the loop variable is being used in an entirely different place, so we end up with `auto &&__range = {}` in both cases, which is not allowed.

```cpp
auto x = {};
// or
auto x{};
```

Are broken in the same way. With an empty initializer list, we have no way of knowing what type the `std::initializer_list` should be.

Answer (score 0):

For the case, you are specifying the type of `x` not for the initializers_list. It will compile if element in initializer_list can be converted x for example I can use `char` instead of `int` it will compile if my types supports this conversion. So `int` is the type of the variable x. Compiler is not getting any clue of the type of initializer_list.

```
for (int x : {})
{
    // do something
}
```

To explicitly tell about your type you have to tell its type like this:

```
for(auto i: std::initializer_list<int>{})
{

}
```

For example this code will print `abc`:

```
for(char i: {97, 98, 99}) 
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: fwiw cases where initializer lists come into existance are listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list